# How to manage multiple version of spark and scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a yarn cluster and another server only used to submit spark jobs to the cluster.

But there are multiple versions of scala say 2.10.x and 2.11.x, also multiple version of spark like 1.6.x,2.0.x.2.1.x.

Is there a way to manage different versions on one server gracefully?

Comment: How about using docker containers? I've never done it. Just an idea.

Comment: But my server is centos 6.x, seems the kernel doesn't support new version of Docker

Answer (score 0):

When you submit something to yarn it doesn't really care too much what is run, as long as it knows where to get the bytecode to execute. Just make sure you have everything installed on both data nodes, in the same path, and submit from the correct version. I've never tried docker, but the docker guys I've spoken to at work don't seem to think it would be a good idea.

Comment: Now I submit jobs using an assembly jar file with whole dependencies.  Submit different version using different spark this is ok. but manager different scala version is not very comfortable.